# JPlayer setMedia mp3

Tags: asp.net, jplayer

I am trying to set a mp3 sound in my JPlayer with the following code :

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            title: "welcome",
            mp3: "C:\Users\test\Desktop\test.mp3"
        });
    },
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_2",
    swfPath: "/js",
    supplied: "mp3",
    useStateClassSkin: true,
    autoBlur: false,
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true,
    remainingDuration: true,
    toggleDuration: true,
    error: function (event) {
        if (event.jPlayer.error.type === $.jPlayer.error.URL) {
            alert("Not found");
        }
    }
});
```

It shows "Not found" in a window while I know the mp3 location is correct.

Comment: It seems like the location has to be a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with this problem just recently. Your code isn't gonna work, because jplayer can't access file from file system.

You need either use some kind of web-server (like nginx) which would serve your media files or use a method in controller which would read file and return stream.